# Remove everything before specific character if found in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to remove everything before the colon, so that only the names are left. My current formula does that but it puts a #!Value error if there is no colon. It should change nothing and just copy the exact name if no ":" is present.

**Column C**

```
        key1:john
        key1:mike
        key1:edmund
        hello
        key3:edmund

etc
```

My formula  =IFERROR(RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-FIND(":",C1)),"")

**Column D**

```
        john
        mike
        edmund
       #!Value
        edmund

etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula nearly does it, with just this one change:

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-FIND(":",C1)), C1) 
                                          ^----- replaced "" with C1
```

This formula gives the results:

```
john
mike
edmund
hello
edmund
```

Comment: So that works but now I have another issue. Now I have 2 seperate columns, one the original and other with the formula ( the one I want). I want to remove the first C column completely form my excel sheet, but if I do that the new Column D can't reference it

Comment: Is there a way to just replace the existing column with the applied formula, all in that column?

Comment: Once you've got the formula results in column D, copy column D and choose the option of 'Paste Values'. That will replace the formulas with the values calculated by the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(":",A1)),A1,MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,9999))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the problem:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(":",C1)),RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-FIND(":",C1)),C1)
```